# android real time image recognition / comparison

Tags: android, image, image-processing

Say I have a set of say 100 stored images (say sports team logos, rather than very similar images like faces) in my android app.  In a manner similar to google goggle's continuous mode, I would like to use the camera to decide which image is being focused on.

What is the best, most efficient way to accomplish this?  Any open source libraries, sdks etc would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like serverside recognition you should check out kooaba's API. its free for small reference databases such as yours and the best in the field...
[Www.kooaba.com](http://www.kooaba.com/)

Comment: I really cannot accept the overhead of an http request (even async).

Comment: It has to be client side (separate solutions for android and ios are acceptable)

Comment: @dldnh i am in same situation, we like to have the server side API available for this process....